# schemacrawler sqlite3 no suitable driver

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, driver, schemacrawler

Using SchemaCrawler for the first time, no previous experience with it.

Ubuntu 16.04.2, installed SchemaCrawler using adriens deb package.

Docs indicate sqlite is supported out of the box with xerial's jdbc driver.

With this command line:

schemacrawler -url=sqlite://db/testdb.sqlite3 -server=sqlite -c=brief -loglevel=CONFIG -i=standard -host=localhost

I get this output:

```
SEVERE: Could not find a suitable JDBC driver for database connection URL, sqlite://db/testdb.sqlite3
schemacrawler.schemacrawler.SchemaCrawlerSQLException: Could not find a suitable JDBC driver for database connection URL, sqlite://db/testdb.sqlite3
    at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.getJdbcDriver(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:370)
at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.createConnectionProperties(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:317)
at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.getConnection(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:147)
at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.getConnection(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:106)
at schemacrawler.tools.commandline.SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.execute(SchemaCrawlerCommandLine.java:129)
at schemacrawler.Main.main(Main.java:90)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
at schemacrawler.schemacrawler.BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.getJdbcDriver(BaseDatabaseConnectionOptions.java:365)
... 5 more
```

No doubt there is a simple solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do not use the `-url=sqlite://db/testdb.sqlite3` command-line argument, since you are already using `-server=sqlite`. Instead, use `-database=db/testdb.sqlite3`

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `-url=sqlite://db/testdb.sqlite3` command-line argument, since you are already using `-server=sqlite`. Instead, use `-database=db/testdb.sqlite3`.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://www.SchemaCrawler.com)